# write a function in pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

This is my query.

```
select origindept, `count(am_course_name)` as total_course
from am_courseoffered
group by origindept;
```

I am trying to create a function who will return this query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION getcourse () 
 RETURNS TABLE (
course_origindept character varying,
course_ count(am_course_name) character varying
)
AS $$
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY select origindept, count(am_course_name) as number_total_course
from am_courseoffered
group by origindept;
END; $$ 

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

There are some error in my function.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "character"
LINE 4:     course_ count(am_course_name) character varying

How i create  function who will return this query.

Comment: I think, you need to be more specific. What errors do you get with that function?

Comment: why not view? or SQL function?..

Comment: Why PL/pgSQL? You can use a simple SQL function as well. Also: those backticks around the `count` function are invalid in Postgres (or SQL in general)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the count function should return a datatype of `bigint`, so I would think declaring the count as a `varchar` would cause a datatype mismatch.  Something like this should fix that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION getcourse () 
RETURNS TABLE (
  course_origindept character varying,
  course_count bigint -- change here
) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  select origindept, count(am_course_name) as number_total_course
  from am_courseoffered
  group by origindept;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I do have to ask, though...  is this an academic exercise to understand functions?  The use case is questionable enough, as a view would be more appropriate.

Comment: it is not working. when i run this function it give some error

Comment: ERROR:  cannot change return type of existing function.  
DETAIL:  Row type defined by OUT parameters is different.
HINT:  Use DROP FUNCTION getcourse() first.

Comment: You have to drop the old function first, like the hint suggests.

Comment: now it give this error                                                                                                             ERROR:  syntax error at or near "bigint"
LINE 5:     course_ count(am_course_name) bigint    )

Comment: You get that error when you compile it or run it?  I wouldn't think that would be a compile-time error

Comment: in compile time

Comment: That's strange.  I just now ran it -- the table doesn't even exist, but it was able to compile just fine.  Did you copy and paste?